# How to get a list of values that are usable with a field in scapy e.g., legal options of DHCP

Tags: python, scapy

How to get a list of values for fields for a layer in scapy?   E.g., is there an easy way to see all the values usable for the 'options' field of DHCP (for example)? (I know I can dig around in the objects' **dict**'s, etc. Is there a better way?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/browser/scapy/layers/dhcp.py) is usually a good place to look, especially when the documentation is sparse. Fortunately the author was kind enough to enumerate DHCP options in `dhcp.DHCPOptions`